# Unexpected token from Powershell when Run Via SSM in Python Script

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, powershell, boto3, ssm

I am sending a powershell script through AWS SSM like this:

```
                                ssm_command_result = ssm.send_command(
                                    InstanceIds=listinst,
                                    DocumentName='AWS-RunPowerShellScript',
                                    Comment='logging the', TimeoutSeconds=600,
                                    DocumentVersion='$DEFAULT',
                                    Parameters={
                                        'commands': [r'function Get-SQLserverKey {\
                                         param ($targets = ".")\
                                         $hklm = 2147483650\
                                         $regPath = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Setup"\
                                         $regValue1 = "DigitalProductId"\
                                         $regValue2 = "PatchLevel"\
                                         For ($i = 24; $i -ge 0; $i--) {\
                                         $k = 0\
                                         For ($j = 14; $j -ge 0; $j--) {\
                                         $k = $k * 256 -bxor $binArray[$j]\
                                         $binArray[$j] = [math]::truncate($k / 24)\
                                         $k = $k % 24\
                                         }\
                                         $productKey = $charsArray[$k] + $productKey\
                                         If (($i % 5 -eq 0) -and ($i -ne 0)) {\
                                         $productKey = "-" + $productKey\
                                         }\
                                         }\
                                         $win32os = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -computer $target\
                                         $obj = New-Object Object\
                                         $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty Computer -value $target\
                                         $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty OSCaption -value $win32os.Caption\
                                         $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty OSArch -value $win32os.OSArchitecture\
                                         $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty SQLver -value $SQLver\
                                         $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty SQLedition -value $SQLedition\
                                         $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty ProductKey -value $productkey\
                                         $obj\
                                         }\
                                         }\
                                         Get-SQLserverKey'
                                        ]
                                    })
```

and powershell returns this error:

`At C:\\ProgramData\\Amazon\\SSM\\InstanceData\\i-03f470cd998dd89ee\\document\\orchestr\r\nation\\0cff4b86-c635-4b6f-a293-1f3fbdc23e1b\\awsrunPowerShellScript\\0.awsrunPower\r\nShellScript\\_script.ps1:4 char:111\r\n+ ... 10\\Tools\\Setup"\\\r\n+ ~\r\nUnexpected token \'\\\' in expression or statement.\r\nAt C:\\ProgramData\\Amazon\\SSM\\InstanceData\\i-03f470cd998dd89ee\\document\\orchestr\r\nation\\0cff4b86-c635-4b6f-a293-1f3fbdc23e1b\\awsrunPowerShellScript\\0.awsrunPower\r\nShellScript\\_script.ps1:5 char:73\r\n+ $regValue1 = "DigitalProductId"\\\r\n+ ~\r\nUnexpected token \'\\\' in expression or statement.`

I have removed every backspace possible but in vain. Any advice appreciated. Thanks.
regards

Comment: Sorry typo. Its still the same error.

Comment: There are two _Right Curly Brackets_ but only one _Left Curly Bracket_ in the Powershell part…

Comment: The Powershell command has mismatching curly braces: one `{` and two `}`. Please copy the commands used verbatim instead of typing. If you type the command instead of copying it, you might fix the issue unintentionally.

Comment: I just posted the chunk of code for more clarity. The number of braces are correct. I have updated the code (still with trimming) to show correct number of braces. The error is still there. Thanks.

Comment: Can you create a MCVE instead? That is, remove _everything_ from the Powershell part. Then add content line-by-line until the error is triggered. As of now, there are extra loops, curly braces still are mismatched, and the offending string `$regpath` is never used. These may or may not have any effect, but it is hard to tell.